# Inserting values into a formset

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a modelform which has a user_id field that I have excluded from the form. This form is made into a modelformset. The reason I have the user field excluded is because it's not an editable value. I don't want that value to go to the HTML form where it can be tampered with by naughty user.

When I try to save this model formset, I get an error saying user_id can't be null. I need someway to add request.user to each form before I save that formset in the view. How can I do this? I know how to add the value to a single instance of a modelform, but I can't figure out how to do it with a formset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not passing request.user to form, there is no direct way that you can get it in form's save method.

However there is a way, if you want user to be available directly at form's save method, from outside the context. Check out, http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookThreadlocalsAndUser .

Answer (score 1):

When you are saving formset remeber to:

```
 if formset.is_valid():
     instances = formset.save(commit=False)
     for instance in instances:
         instance.user_id = request.user.id
         instance.save()
```

You no need anything else. BTW I dont't understand why save user id not user object ?